# System.InvalidCastException when getting SQL Server ROWVERSION into System.Data.Linq.Binary property

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using IDataReader to select all from SQL Server DB which contain a Version column with Data Type ROWVERSION Here is My code:

ItemDetail.cs

```
private Binary _version;
public Binary Version
{
    get { return _version; }
    set { _version = value; }
}

public ItemDetails(int ItemID, string AddedBy, DateTime AddingDate, 
  string LastUpdateBy, DateTime LastUpdateDate,Binary Version)
{
    this.ItemID = ItemID;
    this.AddedBy = AddedBy;
    this.AddingDate = AddingDate;
    this.LastUpdateBy = LastUpdateBy;
    this.LastUpdateDate = LastUpdateDate;
    this.Version = Version;
}
```

ItemProvider.cs

```
protected virtual ItemDetails GetItemFromReader(IDataReader Reader)
{
    return new ItemDetails(
       (int)Reader["ItemID"],
       Reader["AddedBy"].ToString(),
       (DateTime)Reader["AddingDate"],
       Reader["LastUpdateBy"].ToString(),
       (DateTime)Reader["LastUpdateDate"],
       (byte[])Reader["Version"]);
}
protected virtual List<ItemDetails> GetItemCollectionFromReader(IDataReader Reader)
{
    List<ItemDetails> Items = new List<ItemDetails>();
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        Items.Add(GetItemFromReader(Reader));
    }
    return Items;
}
```

I got

> System.InvalidCastException in GetItemFromReader(IDataReader Reader)
>   at (byte[])Reader["Version"])

How can I fix this?
Thank You

Comment: Debug, then quickwatch `Reader["Version"]` and see what type it is.

Comment: Set `Reader["Version"]` to a string, read it manually, then determine its type. Or keep it a string unless you need to use it for calculations, like a new version.

Comment: Reader["Version"] type is byte[8] i tried to use it in function before sending to the version property it worked well but when it sent to the property the exception raised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through many posts here and there I found the solution which is:

ItemProvider.cs
replace:

```
(byte[])Reader["Version"])
```

with:

```
new Binary((byte[])Reader["Version"])
```